# To what extent will Canada's prime minister and its governor general coordinate the upcoming Throne Speech with the queen?

Tags: government, canada, form-of-government, prime-minister, procedure

After seeing Al Jazeera's  [Canada’s COVID-19 recovery plan to dominate Trudeau throne speech](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2020/9/22/canadas-covid-19-recovery-plan-to-dominate-trudeau-throne-speech)

> **Justin Trudeau is set to unveil ‘broad’ plan** that includes healthcare and job support when Parliament resumes Wednesday.

I found [About the Speech from the Throne](https://www.canada.ca/en/privy-council/campaigns/speech-throne/info-speech-from-throne.html) which says:

> #### About the Speech from the Throne
>
> The Speech from the Throne opens every new session of Parliament. The Speech introduces the government’s direction and goals, and outlines how it will work to achieve them. The Senate and the House of Commons cannot conduct public business until Canada’s Head of State or their representative reads the Speech.
>
> **Traditionally**, the Governor General reads the Speech as The Queen’s representative in Canada. In 1957 and 1977, The Queen was in Canada and chose to read the Speech herself. **It is called the Speech from the Throne because the Governor General reads the Speech from the seat—or the throne—in the Senate Chamber reserved for The Queen or her representative in Canada.**
>
> Members of the House of Commons, senators, Justices of the Supreme Court of Canada, and other invited guests attend the reading of the Speech.

and then checked [Speech from the Throne](https://www.canada.ca/en/privy-council/campaigns/speech-throne/speech-from-the-throne.html) includes (embeds) a [video](https://youtu.be/KLHQAi36sZk) of the speech from 2019 and also says:

> On December 5th, 2019, Her Excellency the Right Honourable Julie Payette, Governor General of Canada, delivered the Speech from the Throne to open the 43rd session of Parliament and outline the Government’s agenda.

who is indeed seated on a throne, with Trudeau beside, and the YouTube page links to a transcript: [Moving Forward Together](https://www.canada.ca/en/privy-council/campaigns/speech-throne/moving-forward-together.html) but a cursory reading finds no reference to the queen.

**Question**

Does the speech reflect in any way more than traditionally or symbolically that the Governor General is speaking for the queen or at least reflecting in some way the views of the queen? Does this symbolize any real agreement or coordination **between** the queen as head of state, and the prime minister and governor general of Canada?

Comment: I'm afraid I also read your question as implying that you believe Trudeau himself will be the one to read the speech. One the face of it, @SJuan76's answer seems entirely right to me.

Comment: @DanScally ya I [wrote this](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/57419/will-trudeau-literally-sit-on-the-throne-when-giving-the-throne-speech-will-the?noredirect=1#comment228200_57420) but I grant that the title of the question is *suboptimal* I can't change it now though without SJuan76's permission. Until then, the title might be a frozen down-vote attractor

Comment: [This asnswer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/57420/16047) current sidesteps what #2 asks about, which is the "coordination **between** the queen as head of state, and the prime minister and **governor general of Canada** Hopefully someone will answer that. I can't edit the question and if I ask separately it will be duped.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on this subject, in the section "[Commonwealth realms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_from_the_throne#Commonwealth_realms)" may answer parts of this question. In particular, one of the links from that article [has an FAQ relating specifically to Canada](https://web.archive.org/web/20131019051528/http://www.speech.gc.ca/eng/frequently-asked-questions-faq), though the practice is very similar in the UK, Australia and New Zealand.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff thanks! I'm now wondering if the question of coordination is *too complicated* to answer with a boolean "yes" or "no" or if the answer is "No, but we try not to say it so bluntly." and if that's the reason that the posted answer currently avoids saying either way.

Comment: @uhoh As far as I'm aware, it _is_ stated bluntly. For example, with regard to the UK, [here's the BBC's take on it](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-32816450) ("It is written by ministers but delivered by the Queen"), and the [UK government itself](https://www.gov.uk/government/topical-events/queens-speech-2019/about) ("Although the Queen delivers the Speech, the content is written by the government and approved by the Cabinet").

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff that exactly answers item #2 of my question, thanks! While the BBC [doesn't always get science right on the first try](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/454554/83380) it certainly works as an authoritative source here, and taken together with the gov.uk link I think that it's conclusive. Consider posting a short answer to immortalize it, comments being particularly ephemeral here (a good thing).

Comment: @DJClayworht that part of the question (item #1) can't be edited out or easily clarified now because the prompt answer focusing on that part exists. Ideally someone would have left a comment first but it's fair game to freeze the ambiguity in an answer. Serves me right and I'll do better next time. The question has two items and the second and more interesting one hasn't been addressed yet.

Comment: @DJClayworth no it means I understand Stack Exchange ettiquite! Make a major change to a question after an answer is posted and generally someone will cry "foul!"

Comment: @DJClayworth edit complete, please feel free to edit or adjust further. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Canada as in other UK-style governments, the Queen is the nominal head of state and all government is done in her name. However the actual decisions are taken by the elected government, headed by the Prime Minister. The Queen is constitutionally obliged to follow the policies of her elected government. In Canada specifically the Governor General acts as the Queen's representative.

The Throne Speech sets out the agenda of the government for the forthcoming session of parliament. As such its content is entirely dictated by the elected government. The Governor General, who gives the speech, is obliged to set out the policies the government decides. It is possible that the GG may have some small contribution as to the style or the exact wording, but fundamentally the content of the speech is decided by the government. An examination of past speeches will show that the phraseology reflects that of government statements rather than Governor General speeches.

The Queen makes no contribution to the speech, although if she were to be reading the speech (as has happened occasionally) she might have similar input as the GG.

Comment: I come from a faraway land ruled by small bird that tweets edicts electronically, this method looks better; thank you for your illuminating answer and assistance! :-)